# How come modern electronic devices support charging with various voltages through USB-C?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, usb-c

According to [this blog post](https://cdmanii.com/5864) which tested charging a Samsung laptop through the USB-C port with multiple types of USB-C adapters and external batteries, it seems that that laptop can be charged with 5V, 9V, and 20V. But when I had researched on batteries for Arduino/ESP, each type of batteries had specific charging voltage according to its chemical nature. Then, how come modern electronic devices support charging with various voltages through USB-C? Do they internally convert the input voltages to a specific voltage?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The thickness of a wire in a cable is factor in the current it can carry. Whereas the voltage a wire can carry is determined by the insulation between it and (a) other wires or (b) the outside world, such as people.

To deliver a higher DC charging power to a device (phone, tablet, laptop etc.), either the charger current can be increased, the charger voltage or both.

So by increasing the charger's output voltage and keeping the output current the same, the same USB-C cables can be used to carry higher charging power to the device.

The increased voltage pushing up to the same max. cable current is only for the trip across the cable. Once inside the phone/tablet device, a DC step-down circuit converts the higher voltage to a low battery-suitable varying voltage during charging.

The battery then gets a higher current than what passed through the cable wires, giving the faster charging.

Answer (score 27):

> Do they internally convert the input voltages to a specific voltage?

Yes. The external "charger" is just a power supply, the actual charge control is done inside the device.

Answer (score 14):

Half of the Electrical Engineering is about contacts. The other half is mostly about voltage conversions.

Your nearby power station has a big generator that produces electricity at 1000V or 2000V or something like.

It is not suitable for transmission at a distance so they use a big transformer to make it 50000V or 100000V or even more in order to feed it into the transmission line.

Your city substation consists of few transformers that make this 10000V or 6000V suitable to be distributed between neighborhoods.

Few houses are served by a smaller transformer that makes it 120V and 240V, or, 230V and 400V (depending on where you live) and this is what you get at your wall socket.

Your phone charger makes this into 5V, 9V, 12V or 20V - it even negotiates with the phone what is best for it. If the negotiations fail it gives off 5V and hopes for the best.

Inside your phone, the battery expects something between 3V and 4.2V depending on its state of charge. There is a separate small processor (and usually more than one) dedicated to controlling the voltage converter that charges the battery.

Your phone's main processor expects e.g. 1.1V in order to run properly. Another voltage converter.

The screen pixels in an OLED display are powered each with its own very small controllable voltage converter that makes the pixel bright or dim. Actually, there are 3 of them for each pixel - for each basic color.

The SIM card works at 1.8V. A converter to power it.

The SD memory card works at 3.3V. Another converter.

If you plug something external using "usb-to-go" function, it needs 5V (this is the USB standard). One more converter.

Good luck counting them in a modern phone or personal computer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, voltage conversion has to be done inside the device.

A single Li-Ion battery cell as found in most smartphones has a charging cut-off voltage of about 4.2V. So even for the most basic 5V USB supply you already have to do some voltage conversion (and current limiting) inside the device.

The advantage in having a high supply voltage is lower current through the cable (for the same power) and more allowed voltage drop (potentially allowing for longer cables).

Most laptops use 3 or 4 cells in series (12.6V and 16.8V cut-off voltage respectively), so they even have to do step-up conversion to support charging from lower supply voltages.

Answer (score 3):

#### *USB Charger* is a misnomer

It *is* USB. It's *not* a charger. It's a power supply. These days, quite a versatile one, too.

It *used to be* that some cell phone wall-warts had built-in charging circuitry, to make the phones themselves lighter/smaller. Thankfully, no one designs products that way anymore - just think of the millions of tons of e-waste from all the cell phones of the 90s and early 00s, never mind the inconvenience of having a different charger for almost every device. Yuck.

Charging is handled by internal circuits in the device that has the batteries that need to be charged. In almost all cases, active (switching) voltage conversion is required. Otherwise, the internal charger would:

- be inefficient, e.g. charging a discharged single Li-Ion cell from 5V can be a bit faster when a buck converter is used, instead of a linear pass element,
- or it would not work, e.g. trying to charge an 8V battery (two cells in series) from 5V.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a rather long comment.

It is not just laptops and it's not just USB-C.

I have a Samsung phone that uses a micro-USB socket, An I charge it using an aftermarket "fast charger" that has a standard USB output. Out of curiosity, I some times used an inline USB "tester" of sorts, (a small measurement device that looks like a thumb drive with a screen on it). The tester shows voltage, amperage and power.

I have observed that the same phone some times draws near 0.5A at 5 volts, and some times 0.8 amps at (almost) 9 volts. It seems related to exactly which cable I use to connect the phone to the adapter (My guess is some cables have more pins and so they are able to communicate the charging protocol of the phone, and some cables have the minimum standard 4 pins/wires)

But sometimes, even using a cable that supports the 9 volt charging, the phone seems to choose not to enable fast charging, particularly if it's already at high temperature (warm to the touch).

On another order of things, I have seen DIY projects on various sites on the internet where they use a type of charge/discharge controller or BMS combo that can manage groups of batteries in series and/or parallel. And according to the writer of the article/video, some of those modules can discharge the cells "in series" at the higher voltage, but some can also charge each cell individually at its nominal 4.2 volts, so, according to them, the module can take several different voltages as input and charge the cells in one of different modes depending on those variables. This is opposed to rather simple BMS that can only discharge/charge at "in series" voltage and only use the intermediate battery connection to keep the cells in balance.
The clue that I get as to differentiate the former from the later, is that the simple ones use very thin cables and small solder pads for the intermediate connection, but the "multi voltage" charge controllers use the same size of pad and wire thickness for all battery connections.

(I'm just a hobbyist that sometimes fiddles with electric and electronic components)